Prefix-free binary codes with costs
I came across the following problem:
We would like to generate a prefix-free binary code with $n$ codewords, such that we pay $4$ units for each 1-bit and $1$ unit for each 0-bit used. Let $f(n)$ denote the minimal cost of generating such code. So, for example $f(6) = 35$ since {0000, 0001, 001, 01, 10, 11} has a total cost of $35$ and there is no cheaper solution.
I need an algorithm for computing $f(n)$ that is efficient for large values of n (up to $\approx 10^{13}$).
My solution was that we can assign a Huffman-like binary tree for each $n$ that describes the cheapest solution. If we know the optimal solution for $n$ we can find the cheapest path from the root to one of its leaves and attach a left and a right child to this leaf with codes 0 and 1. This gives the correct solution for the first few values of $n$, however, I am not sure whether it is correct and I did not prove it rigorously.

There's a polynomial time algorithm here : A Dynamic Programming Algorithm for ConstructingOptimal Prefix-Free Codes with Unequal Letter Costs. They give an algorithm which runs in time $\mathcal O(n^{C+2})$ and space $\mathcal O(n^{C+1})$ where $n$ is the number of source symbols and your encoding alphabets have integers costs between $1$ and $C$.
It's kind of too big to mention here, but hope this reference suffices.

+1 Notice however that the problem here is a little less general: the probabilities of each codewords are implicitly assummed to be equal. Further, perhaps the particular value $C=4=2^2$ makes things easier.
